# Is it possible to use alternative Listeners in JMeter after the tests are done?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

I'm familiarising myself with [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) and I've thought of something that's either pretty cool or a very dumb idea.

Whilst reading about [Listeners](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) I noticed the following:

> Note that all Listeners save the same data; the only difference is in the way the data is presented on the screen.

And this:

> Graph Results MUST NOT BE USED during load test as it consumes a lot of resources (memory and CPU). Use it only for either functional testing or during Test Plan debugging and Validation.

So I was wondering: if all listeners receive the same data; why not save that data in a CSV or even XML file, and feed that to a listener afterwards? It would be very resource friendly to have the Graph Results Listener display a graph *after the tests are done*, instead of while testing.

Am I missing something, or is this a good possiblity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do that and i think most guys use it that way only. Instead of CSV and XML files use JTL file format to save the results. In normal scenario one uses command line to run the test and save the data in a file(preferably JTL). After the test is done you can use the JTL file to generate reports with JMeter UI or using other tools like [this.](https://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD)